# Error in microsoft visual studio while using getline

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, getline

when I use `getline` in visual studio, it shows an error. Even though I use header file it still shows the same error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    string s;
    cout << "Enter your name : ";

    getline(cin, s);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
      m++;
   }
    cout << m;
    _getch();
 }
```

Comment: And would you care to tell what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `<string>` not `<string.h>`:

```
#include <string>
```

See [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

The headers string.h, also cstring, contains C-style strings - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring

Comment: Using `#include <string>` worked for me.  Using `#include <cstring>` did not.